# [value='"+ row.type +"']")

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jsp

I don't know what that code meaning?
`$("input[name='modelType'][value='"+ row.type +"']").click();`

This is a jsp file to export a view from spring mvc.

```js
$("#labelStatus").hide();

$("#selStatus").show();
$("#rowID").val(row.rowID);
$("#type").val(row.type);
$("#type").attr("readonly", "readonly");
$("input[name='modelType']").attr("disabled", false);
$("input[name='modelType'][value='"+ row.type +"']").click();
$("input[name='modelType']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#totalCost").val(row.totalCost);
$("#totalRevenue").val(row.totalRevenue);
$("#netRevenue").val(row.netRevenue);
$("#dataStatus").val(row.dataStatus);
$("#useTime").val(row.useTime);
$("#createTime").val(row.createTime);
$ ("#ModifyTime").val(row.ModifyTime);
dialogExportIncome(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [CSS attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#attribute-selectors) that selects:

- inputs
- which have their `name` property equal to "modelType"
- and the `value` property equal to the value of `row.type`.